# django serializer dictfield vs jsonfield

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, django-serializer

I have a column `custom_property` of type `jsonb` in postgres.

I need to validate a payload for this column.

```
payload:

{
    "description": "test description3",
    "custom_property": {
        "access": "Yes"
    }
}
```

I have a serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=500)
    custom_property = serializers.DictField(required=False)
```

Should I use `DictField` or `JSONField` for this column?

It seems that in both case, it needs to be formatted to json string first with `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between these two fields is JSON field store data in native JSON object. and Dictfiled store data in text format as json string.

**JSONFiled will give better performance while working with complex data.**

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield

So I suggest you to use JSONField